# JsonSerializer.Deserialize always returns Null

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Trying to deserialize the following json string:

```
string json = "{\"d\":{\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"http://my.dev.int:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV/MATERIALSet('250')\",\"uri\":\"http://my.dev.int:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV/MATERIALSet('250')\",\"type\":\"ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV.MATERIAL\"},\"MATNR\":\"250\",\"MAKTX\":\"X:K10/MF250\"}}";
```

into Class Object

```
namespace Scanner.Model
{
    public class Material
    {
        public string MATNR { get; set; }
        public string MAKTX { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried using many ways including :

```
Material material = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Material>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    IgnoreNullValues = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
});


Console.WriteLine(material.MATNR); //expected output: 250
Console.WriteLine(material.MAKTX); //expected  output: X:K10/MF250
```

But material.MATNR  and  material.MAKTX are always null .

Comment: You can´t decode it like that. Your json has a completly different structure. Try json2csharp to create a proper model.

Comment: Thank you for the tool ... looks cool il sure use it going forward .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to familiarize yourself more with the Json structure, `Material` is not the type of object being returned in your Json string, it is a nested class of the main object, I have put together a dot net fiddle and tested that this will work for you, as you can see, the main object is what I called `MyJson` which holds one property of class type `MetaData` and a property name of `d`, this class then contains 3 properties: of type `MetaBase` which contains 3 properties of `string` types and 2 other `string` properties, I then deserialize the json string to the main object type of `MyJson` and then write the nested property `MATNR` to the console window, this prints 250, I'm also using, `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` to set certain class properties to the matching values in the json string, you can read more about that here:[system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0)
**fiddle here**: [dotnet-fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5b9whs):

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\"d\":{\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"http://my.dev.int:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV/MATERIALSet('250')\",\"uri\":\"http://my.dev.int:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV/MATERIALSet('250')\",\"type\":\"ZFIORI_SERIAL_NUMBERS_SRV.MATERIAL\"},\"MATNR\":\"250\",\"MAKTX\":\"X:K10/MF250\"}}";
        var myjson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyJson>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(myjson.D.MATNR);
    }
}

public class MyJson
{
    [JsonPropertyName("d")]
    public MetaData D {get; set;}
}

public class MetaData
{
   [JsonPropertyName("__metadata")]
   public MetaBase MetaB {get; set;}
   public string MATNR { get; set; }
   public string MAKTX { get; set; }    
    
}

public class MetaBase
{
   [JsonPropertyName("id")]
   public string ID {get; set;}
   [JsonPropertyName("uri")]
   public string Uri {get; set;}
   [JsonPropertyName("type")]
   public string Type {get; set;}
    
}
```

Comment: Thank a million , works like a charm . Thank you . I am new to C# and thought the deserializer takes care of the sub objects .Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only Material

```
Material material = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(json)["d"].Deserialize<Material>();
```